# Spring Data JPA SQL results and Entity results are different

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, rdbms, querydsl

I have 2 Entities in a Spring Boot Project with Spring Data JPA.
Most of the annotations are skipped for easy understanding.

Entity A

```
class A {
  @OneToMany
  private List<B> bs;
}
```

Entity B

```
class B {
  //...
}
```

and when I run sql with QueryDSL, like this

```
from(a).leftJoin(b).fetchJoin().fetchOne()
```

the result of the real sql query ran on DB
and the real Entity are different.
Like the sql returns 10 of Bs but the A Entity has only 4 Bs.
I don't have any application code filtering Bs.
Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Have you checked to see if any of the results are duplicated or is it returning B objects that aren’t related to A?

Comment: @CalvinP. all the B's id(pk) are unique each other. and all Bs have fk related to A.

Comment: And what is the result of direct SQL query on database